# Prove that the sequence is exact using universal property.

Tags: number-theory, category-theory

Denote by $\mathbb Z_p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers. Recall that $\mathbb Z_p$ can be interpreted algebraically as the inverse limit of the directed system $$...\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/p^{n-1}\mathbb Z\to...\to \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,$$ where each arrow is defined in the obvious way. That being said, the ring of $p$-adic integers is an object $\mathbb Z_p$ with maps $p_n:\mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ to each factor $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$.

Prove that $\mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ is exact, where $h_n: \mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z_p$ is the multiplication by $p^n$, and $p_n: \mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ the map defined in the above paragraph.

**I am looking for a proof using just the universal property of inverse limits.**

We shall show that $\mathrm{Ker}(p_n)\subset \mathrm{Im}(h_n)$ and the other direction is clear. Let $p_n(x)=0=\phi_n(p^nk)$ for some $x\in \mathbb Z_p$ and $k\in\mathbb Z$, where $\phi_n: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ is the canonical homomorphism. Taking $\mathbb Z$ with the canonical homomorphisms $\phi_i: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/p^i\mathbb Z$, we can apply the universal property of inverse limits to obtain a unique arrow $f: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z_p$ to make the universal property diagram commute. Specifically we have $p_nf=\phi_n$. But then $p_n(x)=p_nf(p^nk)$...

I don’t know how to proceed since it shall require the left cancellation which does not seem to hold in this context. Did I do something wrong or should I apply the universal property to another object rather than $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: What is "the projection in the universal property of inverse limits"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Recall that $p$-adic integers can be interpreted algebraically as the inverse limit of the directed system $...\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/p^{n-1}\mathbb Z\to...\to \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. That being said, the ring of $p$-adic integers is an object $\mathbb Z_p$ with “projections” to each coordinate, $p_n:\mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Okay, but the wording is confusing. I recommend that you add your comment to your question and avoid to say "projection in the universal property".  If you want you can say something like "projection from the inverse limit into the $n$-th factor".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. There are some things that do not follow directly from a universal property, for example the fact that $X$ and $X^2$ are linearly independent in the polynomial ring $k[X]$: you need _some_ construction. For colimits, the harder question always seems to be that they are "large". For limits, the question seems to be why they are "small". Here: why is $\ker p_n$ not larger than $p^n \mathbb Z_p$? I.e. why is every element of $\mathbb Z_p$ of the form $p^n u$ with $n \in \mathbb N$ and $u \in \mathbb Z_p^\times$.